# expandable listView recycling causes a bug

Tags: android, expandablelistview, findviewbyid

So I have an expandable listView which each child has a textView in it that I want to increase when that child is clicked!
It works but it's really buggy. I guess Android recycling policy causes this.
What is your suggestion?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5wEm.png

this happens : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrNcT.png

I also have a button to decrease that value which has the same problem.

my Adapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter.

```
//ListView on child click listener
    ExpandList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            TextView tvQt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.child_qnt);
            Button removeButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.child_remove);
            if(tvQt.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                removeButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tvQt.setText("1");
            }
            else {
                tvQt.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(tvQt.getText().toString()) + 1));
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

ps: I'm getting the list from a JSON file over HTTP using Volley. So number of rows varies.

Comment: You can use `View.setTag` to store arbitrary data inside recycled view.

Comment: @dominik4142 Oh I wasn't aware of this, thank you very much. can you please help me implementing it? docs seem unclear to me!  I'd be grateful